# APEX Oracle - display image

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I want to display image from one of the tables, and then with buttons next and previous to change displayed image depend of a row in table. Can anyone show me the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

1. Native: [Carousel Container](https://the%20https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/carousel-region) + [Image Region Template](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/region-image).
2. Plugins: [Slideshow](https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:12410469612279::::P710_PLG_ID:ORCLKING.SLIDESHOW) *Probably the easiest way*. There are more plugins on [apex.world](https://apex.world).

Note: It's important to always include the APEX version you're working on.